# Game center leaderboard showing 2 players on friends and only one on all players

Tags: iphone, game-center

I implemented `Leaderboards` trough `Game Center` in a little game I'm making and I posted scores from two accounts.

So far, so good, but when I checked in Game Center, I saw both my scores in the `friends` list but only mine in `all players` list.

Anyone knows what can cause this?

Comment: Are you using it from the app store, from the sandbox, or from both ?

Comment: From sandbox only. Somehow after several hours both players appeared in "all players" list ... I guess it's something from Game Center (I must specify that my leaderboards were added several days ago, using a group with a couple leaderboards).

Comment: The Game Center sandbox is terribly slow to update. Yes that makes debugging slow but I don't think there's anything you can do about it.

Comment: @RobertL does this thing same with invitations from sandbox GC?

Comment: I never tried invitations but all updates that I have tried in the sandbox game center seem to take a long time (hours to overnight) so invitations probably take a long time too.

Comment: I can confirm that the project I was experiencing issues on the sandbox is working OK on the live environment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had same issue. I need to **send invitations to other accounts**. Only after that I was able to view other account's scores. Hope this works. I don't know about "Players" section though. It shows "No Players".

Answer (score 2):

Yes, after all the issue seems to be slow updates on sandbox game center, so if you implement leaderboards and try it with different accounts, allow for several hours to pass before trying to check if there's a bug on your side.